# C++ 98 time stamp to EPOCH

Tags: epoch, c++98

I have been looking for this but did not find nothing very useful.
Can anyone help me, how can I convert a time stamp into epoch milliseconds only using c++ 98.

Answer (score 2):

- use the c library: ctime.h or time.h
- create a tm structure with the values of date and time entered into the correct fields of the struct.
- use mktime() or gmtime() functions to convert to epoch time in seconds. you can multiply by 1000 for milliseconds, but  the accuracy will not be maintained.